# If I track my next badge, then will it stop tracking my privileges on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

If I track my next badge, then will it stop  tracking my next privilege? Also: Isn't the next badge *already* being tracked on the right side of my 'privilege tracking'?

Comment: It will not "show" the progress on profile page ('cause only one could be shown here), but it is still tracking all privileges.

Comment: Thank you; you should probably put this as an answer, as it answers my question #1. But what about #2?

Comment: On the left side if you pick "track badge" it will show progress for **tag** badge. But the right one can show progress only for common badges.

Comment: What is the difference between the two, though?

Comment: Tag badge - badge for specific tag, like https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/167/review?userid=402819. Common badges are lsited here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Also, could you please put this as an answer? I *will* tick this.

Comment: Sure. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It will not stop tracking it. It just will not show it. Because it can show progress only for one tag at a time.
2. On the left side, if you pick "track badge", it will show progress for **tag** badge, e.g. [your progress for review tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/167/review?userid=402819). But the right one can show progress only for [common badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges).